# Incremently append content from html source in JQuery on added divs

Tags: jquery

I have an example DOM as such below where new child elements can be added:

```
<div id='blog'>
     <div class='item-1'>html content with <b>tags</b> and more..</div>
    <div class='another-item'>more html content with <b>tags</b> and more..</div>
    <div class='item-1'>you <div id='stuff'>get the idea</div></div>
</div>

<div id='blog_article_container></div>
```

And I will need to detach and append these child divs to newly added divs. I need the above to look like this:

```
 <div id='blog_article_container>
      <div id='content_container' class='article_brick'><div class='item-1'>html content with <b>tags</b> and more..</div></div>
      <div id='content_container' class='article_brick'><div class='another-item'>more html content with <b>tags</b> and more..</div></div>
       <div id='content-container' class='article_brick'><div class='item-1'>you <div id='stuff'>get the idea</div></div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated oh Lords of Stackoverflow!

Comment: Please make you question a little simpler to understand!

Comment: Are you saying that u want to add all the div's inside div# blog into div#'blog_article_container?

Comment: I would prefer to remove the original and build a new structure, as I will be removing img content and wrapping in new divs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each inner `div`, move it to the container, and then `wrap` it:

```
$('#blog > div').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#blog_article_container')
        .wrap("<div id='content_container'class='article_brick'>");
});​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/78BAx/

NB: you really shouldn't use the same `id` for the wrapping div.

Comment: That is great, yeah those ids were just an example. Thanks heaps!

Comment: So the each event is similar to a 'for each' loop? thanks again

Comment: @elliotrock yeah kinda, it just means "call this function for each element in the collection".